# mocha assertions passed before page loads

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

The below mocha and webdriverio script is passing assertions before the page loads.

I am not understanding how is it passing everything when probably the elements itself are not yet present. After page loads, I could see that the element is not clicked. Is that a fake pass? How do I fix that in code?

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var should = require('chai').should()
var expect = require('chai').expect()
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

before(function() {

    browser=webdriverio.remote(options)
    return browser.init()

  });


describe('sauce labs page test', function() {
    it('should assert page title', function(done) {




           browser.url('https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/?_ga=1.5883444.608313.1428365147#/');
           browser.getTitle().then(function(title){
          title.should.equal('Platform Configurator');
           });
            done();
    });



    it('should assert sub heading', function(done) {

    browser.getText('h3').then(function(text) {
    text.should.equal('API');
    console.log(text);
   });
   done();
});


   it('should click on selenium', function(done) {

    browser.click('#main-content > div > ng-view > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.choice-buttons.choice-api > div:nth-child(2)')


   done();
});


 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the `done` callback inside the `.then()` handler, otherwise it's called before the browser has had a chance to load the page:

```
it('should assert page title', function(done) {
  browser.url('https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/?_ga=1.5883444.608313.1428365147#/');
  browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    title.should.equal('Platform Configurator');
    done();
  });
});
```

However, this introduces another problem: if the assertion fails, `done` will never get called (because the exception is thrown before it).

Instead, you can use the fact that Mocha has built-in promises support. Instead of using the `done` callback, return a promise and Mocha will handle it (and any exceptions) properly:

```
it('should assert page title', function() {
  browser.url('https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/?_ga=1.5883444.608313.1428365147#/');
  return browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    title.should.equal('Platform Configurator');
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you. that worked.i'll use promises but  for my understanding how doest `done()` know that it has to wait until an element appears on which `browser.getTitle()` can be called and eventually `title.should.equal('Platform Configurator')` can be called so everything aligns. So much of hidden part ,that its hard to understand

Comment: The code you're testing is asynchronous, so as with any async code, you have to wait for the async action to complete before you can continue (by calling `done`, which signals to Mocha that the test is done). With promises, the async action has completed when the `then/onFullfilled` callback is called (or, if you have one, the `catch/onRejected` callback).